# Testing calls/texts to international numbers

Tags: sms, twilio, phone-number

I have a web app that currently sends and receives SMSes in the US, and I'd like to add international support. I want to test sending texts to a few different countries (at least UK, Canada, and Mexico), but I don't have access to any phone numbers in those countries. This means that I can't attempt to send test messages and see the results. Is there such a thing as a "test number" that I can send texts to, and get a response or a report of what was received? Or is there any other standard way of doing this kind of testing? My system is built in PHP and uses Twilio to send messages, though I don't think I necessarily need to use either of those for testing.

The only solution I'm currently aware of (aside from making friends in those countries) would be to purchase Twilio numbers for those countries and configure them to log texts they receive. If there's a simpler solution that would be great.

Note: I've looked at [Twilio's own test credentials and magic testing numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials). Those provide a partial solution -- at least I can test validation for my number formatting -- but I'd still like to see the real result my messages produce on a real phone (or at least a real phone number).

Comment: Any chance you ever found a solution to this?  I would love to be able to test international numbers as well.

Comment: Sorry, I never came up with anything.

Comment: Hi, have you come up with anything regarding this issue? I would love to be able to hear it from you :)

Comment: Sorry, nope. Our international project didn't pan out so I haven't needed to pursue the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to try out telqtest.com

They provide international mobile test numbers to verify delivery of SMS messages, check content, sender ID, SMSC of a message etc. Not sure if they have all the countries which you need but their coverage expands frequently

Comment: Are you affiliated? If so, please specify that in your answer. If users think that you have an affiliation you did not disclose, this could be considered spam.

Comment: I did not share any affiliate links, this is just the link on their website which I use as well from time to time. I am relatively new here, is it prohibited to share the links? If so, I can of course remove it. Although I don't understand how I would be able to help the author without sharing it as I don't know any other companies which provide similar services.

Comment: No, sorry if I gave that impression. It's fine to share links. I was just saying that if you don't work for them, there's no problem, but if you do please say so in the post. That's all, your answer was fine. I'm assuming you don't work for them, but just verifying